# Redmine Plugin - How to use existing helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am created a Redmine plug in for message system. Along with messages user can able to attach files. For that purpose I am trying to use existing AttachmentsHelper.

Here is my sample code

in index.html.erb

```
<% if not @members.blank? %>

<% form_for :note, @note, :url => {:action => 'create', :project_id => @project.id}, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => 'note-form'} do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :p_id, :value => @project.id %>
  <p><%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 40, :rows => 6, :class => 'wiki-edit', :id => 'message_content' %></p>
  <p> <%= render :partial => 'attachments/form' %></p>
  <%= submit_tag l(:button_create) %>

<% end %>

<% end  %>
```

in my controller.rb

```
class CommunicationsController < ApplicationController
unloadable
include AttachmentsHelper

def create
 #code for saving message
end

end
```

The above code not working and also I din't get any error.
What i am missing?

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use existing helpers in your redmine plugin. Try adding

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../../../app/helpers/attachments_helper'
```

at the top of your controller

Comment: I cant see any helper that you are using in your erb file. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
helper :attachments_helper
```